# React-Redux-Form nested component testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-redux-form

I am using React-Redux-Form and React-Bootstrap on client side of application.

I'm stuck on how to testing my components. I have made a small project on github with one of my components named LoginModal: 
[https://github.com/DmitryIvanovIAMM/react-redux-form-login-test/blob/master/src/**tests**/Foo-test.js](https://github.com/DmitryIvanovIAMM/react-redux-form-login-test/blob/master/src/__tests__/Foo-test.js).

To start testing, I am following this tutorial https://www.codementor.io/vijayst/unit-testing-react-components-jest-or-enzyme-du1087lh8.
But when I try to .find() button in my rendered component, the result is an array of length zero. So I can't simulate its behaviour. I try find it (button) several different way but unsuccessful. Please, your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is with the rendering of Modal component that is part of #react-bootstrap. There is a discussion about it on https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/876.
The alternative is to use ReactModal from react-modal. Testing it is described on http://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/05/17/testing-react-modal/

Comment: Thank! This really hepls